# React - setState errir - can't update during state transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When this component is called I get the follow error.

> **setState(...)**: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such
>   as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods
>   should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
>   are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

It seems to be because `{ this.renderCurrentAthlete() }` inside render. When I call `renderCurrentAthlete` I'm trying to let state know who the current Athlete is by running the `this.setState({ currentAthlete: currentAthleteData.Athlete })` but it causes an error. Any advise on how to handle this properly? Also any other advise on the component would be awesome too! Learning so all info is a great help :)

```
class MiniGame extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        score: 0,
        currentAthlete: null
    }
  }

gameData = [
        {Athlete: "Peyton Manning", Img: "someURL"},
        {Athlete: "Tony Hawk", Img: "someURL"},
        {Athlete: "Tomy Brady", Img: "someURL"},
        {Athlete: "Usain Bolt", Img: "someURL"}
]

renderGameButtons() {
    return(
        <div>
            {this.gameData.map((x) => { 
                return(
                    <div key={x.Athlete}>
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={ () => this.answerHandler(x.Athlete)}> {x.Athlete} </button>
                    </div>
                ) 
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

renderCurrentAthlete() {
    const currentAthleteData = this.gameData[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    //console.log(currentAthleteData);
    const imgUrl = currentAthleteData.Img;
    const athleteName = currentAthleteData.Athlete;
    console.log(imgUrl, athleteName);
    //console.log(currentAthlete);
    this.setState({ currentAthlete: currentAthleteData.Athlete });
    return(
        <img className="card-img-top imgCard" src={imgUrl} alt="..."></img>
    )
}

answerHandler(answer){
    // console.log(a)
    // console.log(this.state.currentAthlete)
    if(answer === this.state.currentAthlete) {
        this.setState({score: this.state.score + 10})
        console.log(this.state.score);
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className="miniGameContainer">
            <div className="card card-outline-info  mb-3">
                { this.renderCurrentAthlete() }
                <div className="card-block">
                    <p className="card-text">Pick your Answer Below</p>
                        { this.renderGameButtons() }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you want to setstate for currentAthlete , I don't see you using it

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the state transition in the render block because React automatically updates the DOM via the state, and setting the state in render is probably not a good thing. Maybe try taking this.renderCurrentAthlete out and putting it in a react lifecycle method like componentDidMount() or the one it suggested, and then calling this.renderCurrentAthlete() from that lifecycle method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add method componentWillMount put this code to it and remove from renderCurrentAthlete. method componentWillMount will invoke before render. See more [react lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

```
componentWillMount() {
 const currentAthleteData = this.gameData[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    //console.log(currentAthleteData);
    const imgUrl = currentAthleteData.Img;
    const athleteName = currentAthleteData.Athlete;
    console.log(imgUrl, athleteName);
    //console.log(currentAthlete);
    this.setState({ currentAthlete: currentAthleteData.Athlete });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that last night and it didn't make sense but I came back this morning and seen your response and got it working haha. I'm going to clean stuff up a bit but this is what I ended up with to get it working.

https://hastebin.com/edewajiqus.js